# Click event doesn't register on parent (except on padding)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onclicklistener

I'm trying to register a click event on "video-item", and alert the id. The alert with the proper id only appears when I click on the padding of "video-item"; all other times, it's null...

I've been trying out different solutions on stackoverflow, such as attaching a width/height 100% child element, and adding $event.stoppropagation on the children where I'm clicking.

What am I doing wrong?

Added
**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/b3g68vf8/
 -

*(JSFiddle Note: to show css; controller not working... Didn't have time to fully set it up)*

```
<div class="video-item fade" ng-repeat="chirp in chirps | orderBy: 'date_created': true | limitTo: 6" draggable="true" ng-click="openChirp($event)" id="{{ chirp._id }}">

        <div class="chirp-content-container" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <div class="chirp-favs">23</div>
            <div class="video-thumbnail" 
                style="background:url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ chirp._video.vid_ref.id }}/hqdefault.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
                <div class="interactions">
                    <div class="trash-icon"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tag-details" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                    <div class="avatar" style="background:url(http://www.taste.com.au/images/articles/agt1104-13iw-main10201326.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size:cover;"></div>
                <div class="user-tag-text">
                    <p1>{{chirp.content.post}}</p1>
                    <div class="user-name">Username</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div><!-- Video Item Ends -->
```

This is the event listener.

```
  $scope.openChirp = function($event) {
     var chirp_id = $event.target.id;
     alert(chirp_id);
     $location.path('/workspace').search('chirp', chirp_id);
  };
```

Comment: Are items in this area using css `float` or anything? You might simply need to have either `display:block;` or more likely, `overflow:hidden;` on that `.video-item { }`

Comment: Can you make a plunkr or fiddle so we can see your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ng-click event isn't registering on the parent because the children were layered "on-top" of the parent.

I fixed it using CSS... I added "pointer-event:none" to the outermost child element (in this case "chirp-content-container") inside the parent.

This allowed interactions to pass through the children, onto the underlying parent element, where the necessary attribute, and event listener resides.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute:

```
$event.stopPropagation()
```

Is preventing the click from "bubbling up". If you remove this then it will work.